# AngularJS $service method invocation

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

I am a core java developer, now begining to learn AngularJS.
I am going through the tutorial pages and got the below doubt.

On of the example is

*index.html*

```
<div ng-app="invoice3" ng-controller="InvoiceController as invoice">
  <b>Invoice:</b>
  <div>
    Quantity: <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="invoice.qty" required >
  </div>
  <div>
    Costs: <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="invoice.cost" required >
    <select ng-model="invoice.inCurr">
      <option ng-repeat="c in invoice.currencies">{{c}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <b>Total:</b>
    <span ng-repeat="c in invoice.currencies">
      {{invoice.total(c) | currency:c}}
    </span>
    <button class="btn" ng-click="invoice.pay()">Pay</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

*invoice3.js*

```
angular.module('invoice3', ['finance3'])
.controller('InvoiceController', ['currencyConverter', function(currencyConverter) {
  this.qty = 1;
  this.cost = 2;
  this.inCurr = 'EUR';
  this.currencies = currencyConverter.currencies;

  this.total = function total(outCurr) {
    return currencyConverter.convert(this.qty * this.cost, this.inCurr, outCurr);
  };
  this.pay = function pay() {
    window.alert("Thanks!");
  };
}]);
```

*finance3.js*

```
angular.module('finance3', [])
.factory('currencyConverter', ['$http', function($http) {
  var YAHOO_FINANCE_URL_PATTERN =
        '//query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from '+
        'yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ("PAIRS")&format=json&'+
        'env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
  var currencies = ['USD', 'EUR', 'CNY'];
  var usdToForeignRates = {};

  var convert = function (amount, inCurr, outCurr) {
    return amount * usdToForeignRates[outCurr] / usdToForeignRates[inCurr];
  };

  var refresh = function() {
    var url = YAHOO_FINANCE_URL_PATTERN.
               replace('PAIRS', 'USD' + currencies.join('","USD'));
    return $http.jsonp(url).success(function(data) {
      var newUsdToForeignRates = {};
      angular.forEach(data.query.results.rate, function(rate) {
        var currency = rate.id.substring(3,6);
        newUsdToForeignRates[currency] = window.parseFloat(rate.Rate);
      });
      usdToForeignRates = newUsdToForeignRates;
    });
  };

  refresh();

  return {
    currencies: currencies,
    convert: convert,
    refresh: refresh
  };
}]);
```

In finance3.js, I am not clear when refresh() method will be called. 
There is a call refresh() inside the function($http) of 'currencyConverter' service . But when this statement will be invoked ? 
All I see is we invoke convert() from InvoiceController. But no calls to refresh method.

Comment: The `refresh()` is executed during creation of the `currencyConverter`. The factory then returns a new object (a `currencyConverter`) which can be used by the controller to `convert()` something but also to `refresh()` the currencies (which the example does not do though).

Answer (score 0):

in your code 'finance3' is not a name of you [ng-app](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_intro.asp) in your html code for this reason i dont understand your code. for mora information about implementation of factory and his use I recommend you read this guide carefully [Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide) is a very good guide with examples of code.
and i recommend implement the refresh in your controller.
greetings D

Comment: `finance3` is a new module that is being included as a dependency in the main module `invoice3`. This is totally normal

Comment: is that they did not see in the html you put, I recommend reading the guide I mentioned will give you a better perspective on how to use and distribute the code in angular

Comment: I recommend removing the invocation to refresh () method; in your factory code and put it on the controller to run it when the controller to call your factory by refresh method

Answer (score 0):

The thinking here is that we need to get some external currency data when the service is created AND we also want the possibility of being able to refresh this data at some later point in the application.

Then it makes sense to make a function `refresh` which we'll call once when the service is first invoked, as you noticed by calling `refresh()`. We then expose the `refresh` function as a service method, so any user of the service can request that the service update it's data.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS service/factory works same way as Java Singleton. So when your controller is initialized - code inside

```
angular.module('finance3', [])
.factory('currencyConverter', ['$http', function($http) {
```

Will be executed. It defines `currencies` array and 2 functions. `refresh()` is called once. (You're probably supposed to launch it later when you need to update.)

Here is the Java analog of this service:

```
public class Finance3 {
  public static Finance3 INSTANCE = new Finance3();

  public String[] currencies;
  public Map<String, String> usdToForeignRates;

  private Finance3() {
    refresh();
  }

  private void refresh() {
    new Thread(new Runnable(public void run() {
        usdToForeignRates = Http.get(...)
    })).start();
  }
}
```